# How to change provider state within itself?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
final provider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) {
  Timer? _timer;

  ref.listenSelf((_, flag) {
    if (!flag) {
      _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () {
        ref.read(this).state = true;
      });
    }
  });

  // ... disposing timer, etc.

  return true;
});
```

The above provider returns `true` initially, and I change that value to `false` in a widget and 5s after that, I want to change this value back to `true`. I'm using `listenSelf` but I'm not able to do it.

---

**Note:**

I don't want to use `StateNotifier` with `StateNotifierProvider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ref` of a provider generally exposes a way to modify itself.
In the case of `StateProvider`, you can do `Ref.controller` to obtain the `StateController`

You can therefore do `ref.controller.state = true`

Comment: I'm getting this error `The getter 'notifier' isn't defined for the type 'StateProviderRef<bool>'`.

Comment: Ah sorry the variable name isn't `notifier` but `controller`